# Is there a way to get the x,y location of a CCSprite relative to another parent?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

If I have two layers... Layer A, and Layer B.  And they have different anchor points, so the coordinate (100, 100) would be at two totally different locations...

How can I set a sprite on layer A to be relative to layer B?

In other words, if I was going to add the sprite to layer B, I'd know I want the position to be (123, 456)..  But on layer A, (123, 456) is wrong---  So how could I find out what B's (123, 456) would be in A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the methods below to first convert the coordinates to the world space and then back to the targetNodeSpace:

```
- (CGPoint)convertToNodeSpace:(CGPoint)worldPoint;
```

/** Converts a Point to world space coordinates. The result is in Points.
  @since v0.7.1
  */

```
 - (CGPoint)convertToWorldSpace:(CGPoint)nodePoint;
```

/** Converts a Point to node (local) space coordinates. The result is in Points.
 treating the returned/received node point as anchor relative.